# Calculate how many occurrences are needed to achieve average

Tags: average

I have the following numbers from a ticketing system:

```
Closed Tickets: 10
Transferred Tickets: 10
Total Tickets: 20
```

The current average is: Closed tickets/Total tickets = 10/20 = 0.5 = 50%

What I need to calculate is how many additional Closed tickets do I need to achieve an average of 80% or greater.

So my calculation would be:

```
(Closed Tickets + x) / (Total tickets + x) = 0.8
(10 + x) / (20 + x) = 0.8
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Multiply both sides by $20+x$, which you know is not $0$, and you have a linear equation.